# Is it true that $\log(z^2-1)=\log(z-1)+\log(z+1)$ for all complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, branch-cuts

I know that Log$(z^2-1)\neq $Log$(z+1)+$Log$(z-1)$ for all complex numbers, but is it true that:

$\log(z^2-1)=\log(z-1)+\log(z+1)$, $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}-${$-1,1$}?

My ultimate goal is to separate the original function into these parts and take their different branches as to make the function analytic on my desired domain.

Comment: Your first sentence is inconsistent. The statement cannot be true as $\log$ is not defined for all $z$.

Comment: I had it differently, but the editor changed it. I will change it back. The first sentence is supposed to read log with a capital L, denoting the principal branch of log. @copper.hat

Comment: I guess the editor must've not known the distinction between Log and log in complex analysis. Moreover, I'm only interested where log is defined. (In this case, all points but $-1$ and $1$)

Comment: Are you asking if there is a branch of $\log$ for which the second statement is true?

Comment: $\log(z)$ is holomorphic $\mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}/2i \pi \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you take the multivalued log, then it is true.  That is, $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ always for the multivalued log.  This is why it's often better to do computations with the multivalued log, as long as you realize that you are not dealing with one number but with an infinite set of numbers.